# Error running Opencv sample code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am starting with OpenCV on my new laptop, but there are some errors. I followed all the steps mentioned in the OpenCV tutorials in doc directory. But the sample code just does not work. This is the error:

```
">c:\users\ankit\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(7):
 fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp':
 No such file or directory
1>
1>Build FAILED."
```

I am working on Win7 64 bit machine. I have already included Additional directories and libraries in Property Page. Still it gives me this error. Help.

Comment: Post the entry from the additional include directories field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously entered a wrong include directory. Navigate to included directory and make sure that it contains file `opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp`.

**Update:**
[Here's error doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et4zwx34%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). See all the causes.

**Update #2:**

[About your new issue.](http://msoos.wordpress.com/2010/09/11/0xc000007b-error-solution/)

Comment: I checked the Additional Include Directories like a thousand times, the address is correct. I navigated to the same address and file is present there.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But now there is another error. The code compiles without any error but then a message appears. It's this --> "The application was unable to start correctly(0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application "